# Unity3d web app facebook Sdk payments API Error Code: 1383008

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am developing a facebook game in Unity3d using facebook's new facebook sdk, running the app as a web app inside facebook in sandbox mode.

Today I started implementing a shop in the game for microtransactions using their canvas pay model. I read their documentation and javascript tutorial for payments (they don't have one yet for unity) and created a simple button that when you click you are able to buy some ingame currency(coins).

Now my open graph og:product is tested and looks accurate and my c# code in unity is this:

public void onCoinsClicked()
    {

```
    FB.Canvas.Pay(
        product: "my_url/products/coin.html",
        action: "purchaseitem",
        quantity: 1,
        testCurrency:"EUR",
        callback: delegate(FBResult response) {
        FbDebug.Log("The result of the purchase is: " + response.Text);
    });

    FbDebug.Log("onCoinsClicked: ");
}
```

When i test it using a payments tester user that i have, it throws the following error when displaying the payment popup:

**An error occurred. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 1383008
API Error Description: The app you're using isn't responding. Please try again. If you keep seeing this error, try again in a few hours.**

If some of you kind people have experienced this before please enlighten me :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run your product's URL through the Open Graph Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)? It's possible that a crawler error is causing the issue, and it would be good to make sure that the problem isn't at the data level.

Comment: Hi, thanks fo the answer! This morning the problem somehow "solved" itself and everything is working as intended. Not sure how this happened as I didn't change anything at all. Wish I had some more info for others who also have the same problem.